# Subtracting different numbers in IEEE 754 always nonzero?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

Assuming that `a` and `b` are two IEEE-754 finite FP numbers of the same type, and `a != b` is true, does it always hold that `a-b != 0`? In other words, does `a-b==0` for finite `a`, `b` imply that `a == b`?

Comment: I may be wrong, but AFAIK, no. The result of the subtraction may be a denormal, and AFAIK some compilers regard denormals as 0. Read up about FTZ and DAZ: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523328

Comment: Your question is tagged IEEE-754 and not with any language- or platform- specific tags. If you want answers for specific languages and operating systems, you need to ask questions about those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IEEE-754 arithmetic, for finite `a` and `b`, `a == b` if and only if `a-b == 0`. This is specifically why subnormal numbers were included in the IEEE-754 number system.

Not all languages or implementations of languages conform to IEEE-754. Even if they use IEEE-754 formats, they might not strictly use IEEE-754 operations.

Comment: To make sure I understand this correctly: subtraction of two normal numbers can result in a subnormal so I need to make sure that subnormals are enabled on my machine/my compiler were to rely on this behaviour.

Comment: @MrMobster: yes, although it is probably enabled on most machines.

Comment: Ensuring hardware “features” that replace subnormal values with zero are disabled is insufficient. As the answer states, not all languages conform to IEEE-754. For example, C and C++ allow implementations to evaluate floating-point expressions with more precision than their nominal type. This means `Expression1 == Expression2` might be evaluated with extra bits that result in them being unequal, but, in `a = Expression1; b = Expression2; c = a-b;` the implementation is required to remove the extra precision, which could result in `c` being zero.

Answer (score 0):

`a-b==0` for finite `a`, `b` implies that `a == b` can be deduced from the arithmetic rules in the IEEE-754 standard.

Since practical implementations of many languages may deviate from IEEE-754 arithmetic in ways that affect this, it is safest in programming to say what you mean. If you care about the difference between two variables, ask about `a-b`. If you care whether they are equal, ask about `a==b`.

Comment: The context for my question are geometric computations, where performance matters, but which also must be robust (correct). If I can rely on the sign of the result as an indication of direction, my code becomes much simpler, and most importantly, fits easily into the SIMD paradigm. It is true though that languages generally lack a floating point barrier aka. "do not substitute this fp expression".

Comment: @MrMobster In that case, I suggest identifying the rules for floating point arithmetic for your SIMD processor. If it exactly conforms to IEEE 754, you are OK. If not, ask a new question with a link to those rules.